# Use apply function instead of apply for eval parse instead of loop

Tags: r

It's complicated to explain my use case but I am working on a project that requires parsing text that may throw some errors. I would like to use `tryCatch()` so that as much of the script can run as possible and alert the user that some code failed. I can use a loop for this but I would like to know why this behaviour exists and if there is an apply function that does do the trick.

When I run the loop or use `do.call()` on this parsed object, I get just the expected single error mesage. When I use `lapply()` I get the same error message followed by the ouput of the assignments. I've tried throwing suppress functions around `lapply()` which, perhaps obviously, did not work. and I get similar output for `sapply()` and `map()`. Curious if someone can explain it to me.

```r
test_text <- parse(text = "x <- pi; y <- x; z <- stop()")


eval_try <- function(x) {
  tryCatch(
    eval(x, envir = .GlobalEnv),
    error = function(cond) message("there was an error"),
    warning = function(cond) message("there was a warning")
  )  
}


for (i in seq_along(test_text)) {
  eval_try(test_text[i])
}
#> there was an error


do.call("eval_try", list(test_text))
#> there was an error


lapply(test_text, eval_try)
# there was an error
# [[1]]
# [1] 3.141593
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 3.141593
#
# [[3]]
# NULL
```

Comment: Assign the result of `lapply` to an object and it will "supress" the printing of values.

Comment: Post as the answer so I can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printing you see is the output of the `lapply` function. You can suppress it by assigning the result to a variable or if you really don't care about storing the output, use the below trick with `invisible`.

```
> myfun <- function(x) x
> 
> lapply(1:3, FUN = myfun)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

> a <- lapply(1:3, FUN = myfun)
> invisible(lapply(1:3, FUN = myfun))
```